# How to determine area based on shape bounded by latitude and longitude?

Tags: java, geolocation, geometry, gis, topology

Given an approximate "rectangle" bounded by certain values of latitudes and longitudes expressed in degrees, what would be the best way using a common Java Geometry/Topology library such as JTS(https://github.com/locationtech/jts), to find the *approximate* area of the rectangle expressed in meters/feet squared?

**Assumptions:**

- The rectangle's area will have an upper bound of ~300-500 kilometers^2
- Assuming a tolerance of error of ~ +/- 500-1500 meters^2
- Must use Java *(Currently on Java11)*
- Any common Java Geo/GIS/Topology library is acceptable
- Assume coordinates will be constrained to areas within the Continental USA

**Example**

*Below is an example shape which is an approximate rectangle covering the area occupied by a park:*
[image: Example Shape]

Comment: Use open gis with shape plugin maybe? Is it the conversions from degrees to meters/feet that you need? Because just to find the area with coordinate units is fairly straight forward right? are = the difference of the length coordinates * the difference of the width coordinates?

Comment: There are multiple complications.  For instance, with a sphere the amount of meters per degree changes at different latitudes.  Finding the area of a rectangle on a flat surface is trivial as you indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of a library that can handle reprojection from spherical degrees to a locally planar reference system so you can use JTS to do the calculations.

This [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127921/unit-of-geotools-getarea-function) on [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) gives a longer general example of how to do this using the [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) library.

Since you are constraining your question to the continental USA you have an easier problem and can use a fixed projection such as US National Atlas Equal Area ([EPSG:2163](https://epsg.io/2163)) so a method like:

```
  private Measure<Double, Area> calcArea(Polygon p) {
    try {
      String code = "EPSG:2163";
      CoordinateReferenceSystem auto = CRS.decode(code);

      MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, auto);

      Polygon projed = (Polygon) JTS.transform(p, transform);
      return Measure.valueOf(projed.getArea(), SI.SQUARE_METRE);
    } catch (MismatchedDimensionException | TransformException | FactoryException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Measure.valueOf(0.0, SI.SQUARE_METRE);
  }
```

You can then call it with something like where polygon is a JTS Polygon in lat/lon:

```
Unit<Area> sq_mile = USCustomary.MILE.multiply(USCustomary.MILE).asType(Area.class);
Unit<Area> sq_km = MetricPrefix.KILO(SI.METRE).multiply(MetricPrefix.KILO(SI.METRE)).asType(Area.class);

javax.measure.Quantity<Area> a = me.calcArea(polygon);
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(a.to(sq_km));
System.out.println(a.to(sq_mile));
```